# Tablet and Mobile: align content in the middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on this website http://sg.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/ and what i simply need is to align the content in the middle only on Tablets and Smartphone.

This is how it looks like on iPad for example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rYvT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use a media css statement such as
 `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 769px){}`
and then add the relevant items to it such as

```
.text-r,.text-l{text-align:center}
```

You also might have to overwrite your other css statements by adding a few of the following, remember to use `!important` if the need arises

```
float: none;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two classes to align content **left** and **right** `.text-r` and `.text-l` just change the alignment for these two classes to center for screens less than or equal to 768px:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .text-r,.text-l {
      text-align: center;
  }
}
```